# Oracle Forms 6i: How to manually insert record to database from data block

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a data block 'Employee'; I want to generate ID field value manually when data will be inserted. So I hided the ID field in display canvas. So when I want to click on save button in toolbar usually I write the following code in `Key-Commit` trigger. But the data is not saving to DB.

```
declare
    max_id employee.id%type;
begin
    select max(id)+1 into max_id from employee;
    message(max_id);
    if max_id is null then
        max_id := 1;
    end if;

    insert into employee values(max_id, :first_name, :last_name, :phone);
    IF Not Form_Success THEN            
            Message('Error prevented Commit');
            RAISE Form_Trigger_Failure;
    END IF;
end;
```

I could not understand why data was not inserted or saved. Is my trigger okay?

Comment: Answer: I changed the trigger to On-Insert (not Key-Commit) and it works fine.

Comment: You can try COMMIT after insert too.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you only need to fill the max_id then you should better use a pre-insert trigger to fill the field. And let oracle forms take care of the insert.

Second, you forgot a commit at the end.